# How to differentiate two method parameters of the same class?

Tags: java

I have many methods of the kind

```
doStuff(DataHolder in, DataHolder out)
```

class DataHolder is final. I want to be sure that people do not swap in and out when using the method, which is the simplest way of assuring that? I would rather not use use getters and setters.

Comment: Make more specific classes? Perhaps `DataHolderIn` and `DataHolderOut`?

Comment: @EvanKnowles: "class DataHolder is final", presumably received from a library, not under OP's control.

Comment: Reading the document of the method. So include docs :)

Comment: refactor your method so it'll look like `DataHolder doStuff(DataHolder in)`

Comment: `DataHolder doStuff(DataHolder in)` is not the same thing, since method `doStuff` accesses/modifies some of the infomration already in `out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two wrapper classes:

```
class WrapperDataHolderIn{
     public WrapperDataHolderIn(DataHolder data)
}
```

And

```
class WrapperDataHolderOut{
     public WrapperDataHolderOut(DataHolder data)
}
```

**Note**: Favor composition over inheritance (Composite Reuse Principle)

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple alternatives:

```
DataHolder doStuff (DataHolder in);
```

or

```
class InDataHolder extends DataHolder {
    // Empty!
}
class OutDataHolder extends DataHolder {
    // Empty!
}
doStuff(InDataHolder in, OutDataHolder out);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Pham Trung,

> You can use two wrapper classes:
>
> ```
> class WrapperDataHolderIn{
>  public WrapperDataHolderIn(DataHolder data)
> } And
>
> class WrapperDataHolderOunt{
>  public WrapperDataHolderOut(DataHolder data)
> }
> ```

but I would also add this:

```
public doStuff(WrapperDataHolderIn in, WrapperDataHolderOut out) {
     doStuff(in.getDataHolder(), out.getDataHolder());
}

private doStuff(DataHolder in, DataHolder out) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This way, everything is transparent to the doStuff method.

This is a typical implementation of the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

So one idea similar to Pham Trung's one is

to call doStuff like that

```
in(in).out.(out).doStuff()
```

with `in()` and `out()` returning `this`